# Trying to echo a string will multiple spaces to a terminal but need one string as-is

Tags: echo

trying to do the following:

```
echo "- - 830 "FTL  MFG" -"
```

the `"FTL  MFG"` should be left alone as one entry.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That `FTL   MFG` ends up being *outside* the quotes. What would you like it to output? Do you want those `"` to be included in the output

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "- - 830 "FTL  MFG" -"
     ^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^ quoted
               ^^^^^^^^ not quoted
```

`echo` sees two arguments: `- - 830 FTL` and `MFG -`, and prints them with a space in between. If you want an output with quotes, you need to escape them, or use single quotes to surround the string:

```
echo "- - 830 \"FTL  MFG\" -"
echo '- - 830 "FTL  MFG" -'
```

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes `"` are string delimiters (and strings work differently in shells from what they do in most programming languages). Compare:

```
$ for a in "- - "830 FTL MFG" -"; do echo "$a"; done
- - 830
FTL
MFG -
```

You'll want to either escape the double quotes (so that they are interpreted as literal double quotes) or to delimit your string with `'` instead.

```
%  echo "- - 830 \"FTL MFG\" -"
- - 830 "FTL MFG" -
% echo '- - 830 "FTL MFG" -'
- - 830 "FTL MFG" -
```

Comment: Not that peculiar, you just stick strings together to concatenate them.

Comment: Thanks @roaima: makes no difference in my example but indeed I ought to quote properly in a question about quoting :-) answer edited

Comment: Thanks @ilkkachu: I edited to better specify what I mean (which admittedly is not what I had written before)